# Не могу сбросить пароль биос на материнской плате Asus P8B75-M?

Tags: bios, asus

Не могу сбросить пароль биос на материнской плате Asus P8B75-M?
Сбрасываю пароль около недели и не могу понять, что не так.

Cнимал батарейку CMOS - не помогло, пароль остался, но дата на OS сбросилась. Странная фигня, подумал я и решил передвинуть джампер CLRTC, но ровно такая же проблема - пароль есть, а даты нет!

Далее, я решил прописать мастер-пароль в поле пароля, ровно так же - дата сменилась, а пароль остался.
Ладно, есть куча годного софта, подумал я и нашел прогу comos de animator, сделал всё, как надо, опять то же самое.

Дальше больше, я пошел гуглить инструкцию, описанные в ней способы так же не помогли и ровно так же, дата в ОС сменилась на 2008.

Обратите внимание на мои слова про дату.
Я думаю, что эти способы сбрасывали до дефолта настройки биос, но не пароль к нему. Следственно, я могу предполагать, что при сбросе настроек биоса, пароль не сбрасывается!

Почему так, я понятия не имею.
Напоминаю материнская плат Asus P8B75-M
При включении ПК на экране логотип компании Aquarius.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что по теме данного ресурса.

Comment: @0xdb администрирование же?

Comment: прошей биос и не заморачивайся.

Comment: @andreymal Да, соласен, но у вопросов по администрированию есть тоже границы. Если вопрос по железу связан с системой для разработки ПО, то ок, а если починить пк, да в игры погонять, то нет. У меня что-то закралось подозрение, что это как раз последнее.

Comment: На какое время вы снимали батарейку? Пишут чтобы пароль сбросить нужно ждать сутки (и конечно не включать питание компьютера). Остальные способы не всегда сбрасывают пароль.

Comment: @0xdb не стоит закрывать данный вопрос, результаты ответа на него, могут быть полезны для многих пользователей, а также использоваться системными администраторами в их работе.

Comment: Отключить питание от платы, вынуть батарейку и коротнуть отверткой контакты на батарейке. Может быть на кондерах держится напряжение и память не сбрасывается до конца.